# Adding attributes using closest heading tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML from a system that I can't alter. I need to add the 'for' attribute to the label elements and an 'ID' to the input elements. I want to use the content of the 'H6' directly above each set to populate these attributes.

I'm trying to get this to work with .closest but getting nowhere. Without targeting the closest H6 then each attibute has the H6 content displayed twice,i.e Title1Title2

```
<h6>Title1</h6>
<p>Some intro text</p>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<h6>Title2</h6>
<p>Some intro text</p>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('label').attr("for", $( "h6" ).text());
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("ID", $( "h6" ).text());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic:

- First, loop through all `h6` tags
- Get the `text` based on the current element using `this`
- Use `.nextUntil('label').last().next()` to get labels after each `h6`
- Update attributes next for `label` & `input` element inside `label`.

```js
$('h6').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  var $label = $(this).nextUntil('label').last().next();
  $label.attr("for", text);
  $label.find('input').attr("id", text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6>Title1</h6>
<p>Some intro text</p>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<h6>Title2</h6>
<p>Some intro text</p>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might go with `prevAll()` and a filter to get the first instance:

```
$('label').prevAll('h6').first();
```